# How to fake a non-existent XML node using XPath?

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

I know it's a bizarre question!

The requirement is due to the existing code which expects the result of the XPath query to be a single node.  Unfortunately, we are unable to make code changes at this time due to factors outside of our control (unless no workaround exists, which would probably mean that we would have to delay our release).

In my case, the XPath currently returns an integer value (count):

```
count(/someNode/node)
```

The code uses `XPathNavigator.SelectSingleNode()` method, which, of course, fails because the result is not a node.

Instead, I need the XPath to return a node, albeit a fake one.  Is it possible?  Note that because .NET is used, the XPath would have to be 1.0 (not 2.0).

P.S. And, yes, we'll look into refactoring the code in question ASAP!

Comment: I think there must be some other requirement that I'm missing. If you just need the XPath to return a node, you can just change your XPath to "/". Do you actually need your XPath to return a node *whose text content is equal to the value of `count(/someNode/node)`*?

Comment: BTW +1 for usefulness of the question. I've often wanted to be able to construct a node in XPath. Of course if you could do that, with all the bells and whistles, you'd be close to replicating XSLT. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need your XPath expression to return a node whose text content is equal to the value of `count(/someNode/node)`, you could do it like this:

```
"(//text() | //*/@*)[. = count(/someNode/node)]"
```

That might be grossly inefficient, depending on what your input document is like; and it might very well fail if there is no text node in the input document that contains the right number. However in some circumstances it could do the trick, and might help you avoid delaying your release.

For example, if your input XML is small, and the range of possible values for the `count(...)` is limited, and if you are able to make changes to the XML, then you could include extra text or attribute nodes in your input XML to make sure the needed numbers are available.

Comment: Thanks, @LarsH. That's an interesting/creative idea.  Unfortunately, the likelihood of the count value appearing in the document is rather slim and we also don't have control over the incoming XML.

Comment: Although this doesn't resolve the problem (due to XPath limitations by design), this approach is definitely very close to a workable solution.

Comment: @IgorPashchuk: I should give credit to the Piez method (http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9945e300), which is where I probably got the idea from.

Answer (score 2):

XPath selects nodes in the input document, it can't create new ones or "fake" ones so I think if you want to evaluate the expression `count(/someNode/node)` you need to use the `Evaluate` method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c16b7x8.aspx and not `SelectSingleNode`.

Comment: Thanks, Martin.  The Evaluate() method is indeed what I would use for this scenario.